# Не отображает список listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

не могу понять в чём проблема вот исходный код:
MainActivity.class

```
package com.nikita.mozhaev.notepad;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        notes.add("Example Note");

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Получаю белый экран
https://prnt.sc/ul1rxz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код коректен, проблема была с эмулятором на реальном устройстве всё работает. Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]